# Choosing on the Number Line

Tags: probability

Suppose a real number is chosen from the interval [-1, 1].

My homework asks to find the probability that the number is positive, and using geometric probability, I get 1/2.  Simple, right?

However, the next question asks what the probability of choosing a nonnegative real number is, and I do understand it is also 1/2

After finishing my homework, I'm wondering: Is it possible to choose 0, and what would the probability of choosing 0 be?

Comment: This is a subtle and good question to have. The short answer: for continuous random variables $\mathbb P(X = x) = 0$ for all $x$. You can also see this by asking yourself for a continuous function $f$ what is $\int_a^a f(x) \ dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the distribution is uniform, the probability of choosing $0$ from $[-1, 1]$ is zero. But you may say, if the probability of choosing any given number is zero, then the sum of all the probabilities would also be zero; but remember we are dealing with infinity.